# Is it possible to resize a mounted LVM partition on the fly?

Tags: redhat, lvm, storage-area-network

Situation: We have a server that has a 40GB SAN (Fiber Channel) mounted as /opt/application.

If the LUN is expanded to 60GB, what needs to be done to expand /opt/application on the RHEL-server to 60GB having only 1 LVM partition?

One option is adding a second LVM partition with fdisk and using lvextend to add this partition, but what if we want to stick to having 1 LVM partition on the disk?

What is the best way to expand the LUN from 40GB to 60GB? An unmount is possible if necessary, it's better than adding a second LVM partition and using lvextend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll assume your underlying PV is multipathed.

- View the partition table of the LUN in exact sectors
  `fdisk -ul /dev/mpathX`
- Re-scan the LUN
  `echo` into `rescan` or `issue_lip`, or run `rescan-scsi-bus.sh`, or however you do it
- Confirm the block device now has the larger size
  `fdisk -ul /dev/mpathX`
- Edit the partition table
  `fdisk -u /dev/mpathX`
- Delete the partition, re-create the partition with the same starting sector but a new end sector which reaches to the new end of the larger block device.

  If your partition starts at an early sector like 63 but fdisk will only let you start a partition at 2048 or later, then create the partition starting at 2048, then go into "expert mode" and "move beginning of data" back to 63.
- Unmount your filesystem
  `umount /opt/application`
- Set the VG inactive
  `vgchange -an /dev/mapper/vg-lv`
- Have the system recognise the new partition table
  `partprobe /dev/mpathX`
- Grow the PV to the new size of the partition
  `pvresize /dev/mpathX`
- Set the VG active
  `vgchange -ay /dev/mapper/vg-lv`
- Resize the LV and its underlying filesystem
  `lvresize -r -l+100%FREE /dev/mapper/vg-lv`
- Mount the filesystem and confirm its new size
  `df -h /opt/application`

Disclaimer: These are the right steps to the best of my knowledge. Make a backup. Do a test run in your development environment before trusting your production data to some random internet commenter on Serverfault.

Comment: Alternate choice, create a new 60GB LUN.  Allow the server to see it.  Do a pvcreate and then vgextend the existing LVM to it.  Then do a pvmove to migrate all extents from the old 40GB LUN device to the new 60GB LUN device.  Then you can remove the old LUN and do the lvresize (you'll also need to run your file system resize command).

Comment: And if you go with the new-LUN route, note that the PV doesn't need to be a partition - it can span the raw LUN (no need for fdisk/partition table). If your current PV was on the raw LUN, you'd be able to expand the PV online (scsi `rescan` then `pvresize`).